# Get list of items of type T from a class entity

Tags: performance, list, c#-4.0

I have Class A with following structure

```
 public class A
  {
   public list<B> Items // where B is a class entity
  }

  public class B{
    public List<B> OwnItems;
    public List<C> Items // where C is a class entity
   }

  public class C
  {
   public string name;
   public string Address;
   public int Age;
   public double Salary;
  }
```

How to get list of C class entities from Entity A using c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LINQ with the help of **[SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx)** for this:

```
A a = new A();
// Populate a's `Items` property...
....

var allC = a.Items.SelectMany(b => b.Items.Select( c => c)).ToList();
```

Comment: Hey that worked perfectly , but there are some cases Entity B can have List<B> as its property..how to work in such situation..Please refer my question which i have updated

Comment: That's a totally different situation, since now in your new scenario you'll need to do this recursively...

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = new A();
var bList = a.Items;
var cList = new List<C>();
while(bList != null && bList.Count > 0)
{
    foreach(var b in bList)
        cList.AddRange(b.Items);

    bList = bList.SelectMany(b => b.OwnItems)
                 .Where(b => !bList.Contains(b))
                 .Distinct().ToList();
}
```

not the best to me, but will work